# is there a cursor for parsing json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Consider the following JSON data:

```
{
    "0": {
              "element1":"value1",
              "element2":[
                   {
                       "ele2subelement1":"ele2subvalue1",
                       "interestingelement2" : {
                           "0":"1",
                           ....
                           }
                   }
              "element3":[
                   {
                       "ele3subelement1":"ele3subvalue1",
                       "interestingelement3" : {
                           "0":"2",
                           ....
                           }
                   }
          },
    "1": {
              "element1":"value1",
              "element2":[
                   {
                       "ele2subelement1":"ele2subvalue1",
                       "interestingelement2" : {
                           "0":"1.1",
                           ....
                           }
                   }
              "element3":[
                   {
                       "ele3subelement1":"ele3subvalue1",
                       "interestingelement3" : {
                           "0":"2.1",
                           ....
                           }
                   }
          }        
}
```

Now let's say i am interested in both top-level keys 0 and 1.
Inside those, i am interested in interestingelement*. 
I need to perform calculations based on the values for that key in the following manner.

- Take 0.element2.interestingelement2.

  Take 1.element2.interestingelement2.

  Perform calculations on corresponding values.

  Store the result in a similar JSON format.

For example:

- Multiply 0.element2.interestingelement2.0's value and
  1.element2.interestingelement2.0's value.

  Store the value in a similar JSON format.

  Move on to the next calculation.

How would i go about doing this in javascript?

I guess i could store these in separate variables, have a parser go through them until it hits an interesting element in both variables.

Then perform the calculation and store the value. And then continue on it's way until it hits the next one.

What if there are more than two elements? And if the calculation is complex?
For example: A/B + C

Comment: Turn it into a JavaScript object graph (arrays and objects). Use it as a JavaScript object graph.

Comment: The question is "How can I iterate over object values .." or "How can I access a property .." and has nothing to do with JSON (which is just a text representation).

Comment: Are you asking about objects or are you asking about JSON? JSON is a text format like XML or YAML. Objects are data structures in javascript (other languages like C++ and Java call them objects as well btw)

Comment: i'm sorry, my terminology could have been better. will update.

Comment: will look into javascript object graphs. How do you propose iterating over both elements at once?

Comment: Just parse the JSON into a JS object literal, then perform the operations on the object and parse it back into the JSON file.